# How can I use ! expansion in a ZSH script?

Tags: shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I'd like to write a function that makes it easier to use parameters of the previous command more easily, such as `!:1`. I've read that in bash this can be accomplished with:

```
set -o history 
set -o histexpand
```

So how could I write a zsh function that would have access to `!:1`?

Comment: You cannot use history expansion inside scripts in Bash, either; it's exclusively an interactive feature.

Comment: That's too bad, but if that's the answer there's no way around it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @tripleee No, it's only on by default in interactive `bash` shells. The two  `set` commands in the question enable it in non-interactive shells as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of, you cannot use `!` in ZSH scripts.

But there are other ways to access your command line history:

```
$ echo foobar
foobar
$ fc -l -1
501  echo foobar
```

Of course, this does not work from inside a script either as it still tries to access the history, which simply does not exist for non-interactive zsh. But you can incorporate it into a function in your `.zshrc` and pass it to a script from there:

```
function histaccess ()
{
    lastcmd=$(fc -l -1)
    somescript ${(z)${lastcmd#*  }}
}
```

Calling `histaccess` will retrieve the last command line (`fc -l -1`), strip the history number (`${lastcmd#*  }`), split it like zsh would (`${(z)...}`) and pass it to `somescript`. In `somescript` you can do anything further. If you want to use ZSH for scripting please note that arrays begin with `1` unless the option `KSH_ARRAYS` is set, while history expansion begins with `0`, with `!:0` being the command name.

If you want to avoid filling your history with calls of `histaccess`, you can bind it to a key (for example `Alt+I`) in your `.zshrc`:

```
zle -N histaccess
bindkey '^[i' histaccess
```